# Extract and merge columns in a CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

Here's my situation....I have two CSV files (file 1 and file2). File1 has about 15 columns and file2 has about 10 columns. I need to grab all 15 columns from file1 and extract just column 13 from file2 and merge all 16 columns in a new csv file called "final.csv" Please suggest me some ideas as to how I can make this code work. Here is what I have so far...

```
 import csv
    File1 = 'F:\somedata\somefolder\file1.csv'
        File2 = 'F:\somedata\somefolder\file2.csv'
        File3 = 'F:\\somedata\somefolder\final.csv'
        with open('r', 'File1' and 'File2', 'rt') as f, open('r', 'File3', 'wt', newline='') as f_out:
            headings = next(iter(csv.reader(f)))
            csv.writer(f_out).writerow(headings)
            csvout = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=headings)
            for d in csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=headings):
                csvout.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant column 8 from file2.csv.

Comment: probably not the best way but the quick and dirty way would be to read each row into an array setting column numbers as index. From index then you can grab the 13th column, then just iterate through the array to rejoin as required, not too sure about the code right now but logic is comment worthy :)

Comment: What's the issue you're having right now? (Other than the indentation). You should take the time to read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using pandas load your files as tables. Then use indexing to select the columns you want, merge the files then create a new file. Obviously you cant select the thirteenth column from file2 if it only has 10 columns, so here I am assuming you DO have 13 columns in that file.

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_table('F:\somedata\somefolder\file1.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)
file2 = pd.read_table('F:\somedata\somefolder\file2.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)
file2_short = file2.ix[:,12:13]
new = pd.concat(file1, file2_short, axis=1)
new.to_csv('F:\somedata\somefolder\newfile.csv')
```

This assumes that you want column 13 from file 2. If that column has a header (of course you would remove the 'header = None' part) you can select by that instead...

```
file2_short = file2['col_13']
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to do this without using Pandas? I am having trouble installing Pandas as it failed. I did a PIP install Pandas and it is complaining about some Visual C++ component not installed. I am trying to achieve this without having to import external components and just use what is currently available with Python 3.

Comment: Ah, that might me slightly more tricky. Personally I would re-install the entire Python package through Anaconda which comes with Pandas and other key packages pre-installed [link](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Otherwise I am afraid I cant help much.